# CoreData in XCode create a NSFetchRequest returning all entities from today

Tags: xcode, core-data, nsfetchrequest, nsexpression

Is there any solution to create a NSFetchRequest in the XCode view which is returning all entities from "today"? In the view you can only specify a date but not dynamically define today.

[image: Create a NSFetchRequest in XCode]

I know that I can also create a NSFetchRequest directly in the code and there I can specify the date dynamically but I was just wondering if this is also possible directly in XCode without writing any code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible. You can specify a variable `$TODAY` and use it in code like so:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest =   [self.managedObjectModel
  fetchRequestFromTemplateWithName:@"ScanFetch" 
  substitutionVariables:@{@"TODAY":[NSDate date]}];
```